# i18n with compiled templates?

Tags: templates, node.js, internationalization, hogan.js, socketstream

I have templates that are compiled on production builds using socketstream and Hogan.js.  The problem is that when I am on the client side and fetch the template, I need to bind it to a JSON language file with a set of key value pairs.  The files have the naming structure such as de.json and have contents such as:
{
  "thanks": "danke"
}

If on the server I know what language the user has selected, how do I deliver the correct language json file to the the client in order to render the correct view for the user?

Comment: does your clientside i18n library not load the resource file like in http://i18next.com (node.js and clientside)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the language in a session's variable? It'd allow you to easily know what to render.

```
res.render( user.language + '.json' );
```